# Change Mouse Cursor Icon(.ico) in Visual Studio 2010 (GUI)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface, cursor, icons, mouse

Now, I have an icon (Path : Mini-Project\Mni_Project\Mni_Project\Icon\mouse_cursor.ico).

[image]

I want to change the mouse cursor image to this icon.

There is no way for me to change the cursor image in the property window.
[image]

I have tried : (Do not work.)

```
//this->Cursor = System::Windows::Forms::Cursors::Hand;
this->Cursor = LoadImage(NULL, "Icon\\mouse_cursor.ico", IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
```

How can I change the mouse cursor icon?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
this->Cursor = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Cursor("Icon\\mouse_cursor.ico");
```